# Selecting Combobox on Userform from one workbook causes problems with activated sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, MacroBook.xlsm has code and userforms contained in it. OtherBook.xlsx has no VBA code and is only acted on by the code.

I have a Userform containing a ComboBox and 2 buttons. Button 1 launches a function that copies data from OtherBook into a temporary sheet in MacroBook, gets all unique items from the range and then deletes the temp sheet.

```
Function GetListOfEditors(ws As Worksheet) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    i = ufAddToDraftWorking.iEdDestRow

    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim lRow As Integer

    'Create a temp sheet to store data
    Call CreateSheet("TempSheet")

    'Copy complete list of editors to temp sheet
    ws.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(i - 1, 5)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("A1")

    'Use worksheet function to remove duplicates from both columns
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempSheet").UsedRange
    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempSheet").Activate

    'Store updated data
    lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 2))
    data = rng2

    'Delete Temp Sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempSheet").Delete

    'Return List of Unique Editors
    GetListOfEditors = data

End Function
```

This range is then stored into a ComboBox on the Userform. At this point OtherBook is in focus on the screen. As soon as I select the Userform e.g clicking the ComboBox, MacroBook is now in focus.

Clicking the next button on the Userform makes some changes onto a sheet in Otherbook. During this MacroBook is still in focus.

```
Sub AddApprover(ApproverName As String)

    Dim wbDraftPricing As Workbook
    Dim wsEditorSheet As Worksheet

    Dim i As Integer

    i = ufAddToDraftWorking.iEdDestRow

    Debug.Print Application.ScreenUpdating
    If FileHandler.IsWorkBookOpen(Globals.DraftWorkingFormulasPath) = True Then
        Set wbDraftPricing = Workbooks(FileHandler.FileNameFromPath(Globals.DraftWorkingFormulasPath))
    Else
        Set wbDraftPricing = OpenDraftWorkingFile()
    End If

   'OtherBook is still not put into focus here 
    Set wsEditorSheet = wbDraftPricing.Worksheets("Editor List")
    wbDraftPricing.Activate
    wsEditorSheet.Activate

    With wsEditorSheet

        'Add Approver from dropdown list on userform
        .Cells(i, 5) = ApproverName
        .Cells(i, 12) = .Cells(i, 4)
        'Add Vlookups to get correct naming from sharepoint
        .Cells(i, 16).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & i & ",V:W,2,FALSE)"
        .Cells(i, 17).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E" & i & ",V:W,2,FALSE)"

    End With

    wbDraftPricing.Activate
    wsEditorSheet.Select

End Sub
```

If I then select OtherBook from the taskbar this obviously comes into focus. Clicking into this sheet however is where the issue lies. If I try and select a cell in OtherBook what is actually selected is a cell in MacroBook. This effect carries over to clicking the close button on OtherBook actually closes MacroBook.

To fix this I have to click into the Userform, then click into MacroBook then I can open OtherBook and select cells as normal.

In the function AddApprover I have marked with a comment where I had expected OtherBook to come into focus but this does not happen.

Any help or explanation why this is happening would be most appreciated.